# Active Record Querying - Sorting by the count of an attribute that meets a query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I am writing an app that allows users to rate pictures. I'm trying to create a table that sorts categories based on the number of featured pictures they contain. For example, it would look something like this.

```
CATEGORY    FEATURED IMAGES
Landscapes        5
Animals           3
Forests           2
Oceans            2
Sunsets           1
```

Above, each category is sorted by the number of featured images it contains. If multiple categories share the same number of featured images, those categories are listed alphabetically (example: Forests, Oceans).

```
Featured image: An image with a star rating of 4 or higher.
```

I tried the following

```
Picture.order(stars: :desc).where('stars >= 4').order(category: :asc)
```

Here I'm sorting each pictures by its number of stars(rating) and I only want to select pictures whose number of stars is at least 4. Then I ordered it by categories.

I also tried

```
Picture.where(category: 'Landscapes').where('stars >=4').count
=> 5
```

I first need to find that answer for every category with at least 1 featured image.

```
array = []
array.push(Picture.where(category: 'Landscapes').where('stars >=4').count)
=> 5
array.push(Picture.where(category: 'Animals').where('stars >=4').count)
=> 3
array.push(Picture.where(category: 'Forests').where('stars >=4').count)
=> 2
array.push(Picture.where(category: 'Oceans').where('stars >=4').count)
=> 2
Picture.where(category: 'Sunsets').where('stars >=4').count
=> 1

array
=>[5,3,2,2,1]
```

This successfully sorted the categories by their number of featured images, but it seems inefficient.

I then might try something like this

```
<tbody>
  <% Picture.where('stars >= 4').each do |picture| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= Picture.category %></td>
    <td><%= array[num]] %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

To obtain the appearance of the first code black.

Is there any way I could store that query in a loop, to quickly find those values for all categories?

I know of the Ruby methods sort and sort_by but how can I use it to sort the results of the above query.

Basically, I'd like to sort categories by the number of featured images they contain. I'd like to have the category name and then the number of featured images next to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple orders within the same call. This allows for multiple column sorts like you want. This will first do stars and then if there are multiple with the same it will then sort by category.

```
Picture.where('stars >= 4').order(stars: :desc, category: :asc)
```

To get the count of how many are in each category use the group method.

```
Picture.where('stars >= 4').group('category').count()
```

That should return a hash with the keys as the categories and the value as the number of pictures that have stars >= 4.

Comment: Great work. That returns an array of records. What I'd like though is to count the number of featured pictures in a category though.

Comment: @DarkMouse I didn't quite understand what you were going for at first. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Amazing, that works perfectly. I will accept this answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank ericsaupe for helping me out here. That allowed me to get to find a solution.

```
<tbody>
<% Picture.where('stars >=4).group('category').count.sort_by{|key, value|value}
.reverse.each do |picture| %>
  <tr>
    <td> <%= picture[0] %></td>
    <td> <%= picture[1] %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Output

```
Landscapes        5
Animals           3
Forests           2
Oceans            2
Sunsets           1
```